# Handling certain errors in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, email-validation

I'm looking to create certain events when certain error codes occur in my program. For instance, if there is an error code 200, I need to let the user know they are missing the username field. Or for an error code 125, I need to let them know they did not enter a valid email address when creating for an account. How do I target these error codes specifically? I have tried the code below with no success, what am I doing wrong and is this possible?

```
if error.code == 125 {
        var invalidEmail:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: Please try again, message: "That does not look like a real email address. Please enter a real one.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        invalidEmail.show()
    }
```

The error that xCode is telling me is that I have an unresolved identifier 'error'. There is an instance of this in the parse starter project file 'AppDelegate.swift' that calls the following code and it seems to work perfectly fine.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        println("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        println("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}
```

## My code

```
@IBAction func signupTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let fullname = fullnameField.text
    let email = emailField.text
    let username = usernameField.text
    let password = passwordField.text

    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = username
    user.password = password
    user.email = email
    // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
    user["fullname"] = fullname

    if error.code == 125 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please try again", message: "That does not look like a valid email address.", preferedStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true)
    }

    if fullname.isEmpty || email.isEmpty || username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
        let emptyFieldsError:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "Please fill out all the fields so that we can create your account.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        emptyFieldsError.show()
    }

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        } else {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to call 'show' message?

Comment: You doesn't seem to call `show` on your `UIAlertView`, which is by the way deprecated.

Comment: I have made changes to the post regarding implementations I have made based on the comments received.

Comment: Note ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32085632/294884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `error` defined where you have your code. You can only reference `error` from inside a scope in which it exists.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
        // PUT YOUR ERROR HANDLING CODE HERE
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Larme already pointed out, `UIAlertView` is deprecated, so you should use `UIAlertController`:

```
if error.code == 125 {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please try again", message: "That does not look like a valid email address.", preferedStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is helpful but I am still getting an error that error.code is an unresolved identifier 'error'.

Comment: @TrentonTyler where do you check for errors? Inside Parse block?

Comment: No, xCode is not building my app for the iOS Simulator because of this error. So xCode is giving me this error, but I import Parse in the file so I am not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: @TrentonTyler I mean where in code are you trying to show the alert

Comment: @IBAction func signupTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

Comment: @TrentonTyler can you please post full code of this function?